# An ad for Gaming?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

I recently noticed a lot of SE sites are cross promoting at our big sister site: [Arqade (AKA Gaming.Stackexchange.com)](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/).  I think there is enough cross interest (and the occasional cross question) that it makes sense for us to put up an ad there.

> [Community Promotion Ads - 2013](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5602/community-promotion-ads-2013)

So, anyone have an ad suggestion?

Comment: Most of the existing cross-promotional ads I see there highlight the synergies between Arqade and other sites. The Sci-Fi ads in particular advertise that people can ask lore questions (that might otherwise be off-topic on Arqade) at the other site. I'm failing to come up with a similar synergy between us and Arqade, or some need that Arqade users might go to Arqade for but that we can better fulfill. "When you want to play your favourite videogame with paper and pencils" doesn't really have a ring to it.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I think that's more of a nice to have rather than a requirement. Chess and Sci-Fi both have ads more along the lines of "you like games? You might also like us!" Chess is the top rated of the SE links, for example.

Comment: @AceCalhoon My thoughts were "we're more related than *chess*.

Comment: @Ace Yeah, I was thinking of it less as a requirement than just a nice model to use, but failing to come up with something fitting. But now that you say it, "You like games? You might also like us!" with the logo and a "Roleplaying Games SE" label or something might do just fine.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie You could reference the dozens of video games directly based on PnP systems?  Baldur's Gate, KoToR, etc...

Comment: Yeah, I just don't know how to phrase the value proposition for that. "Liked *Baldur's Gate*? Don't wait for sequels—make your own story."? But that advertises RPGs in general, not so much us.

Comment: Learn about the system behind Baldur's Gate and Icewind Dale. Learn about telling your own stories in the world of Mass Effect: Role Playing Games.SE: We work on the imagination engine! (okay that last bit's a bit ... silly)

Comment: I think just "Roll for initiative!" with a D20 and a sword and maybe a dragon could work if properly arranged.

Comment: We could ask Jin for art :)

Comment: I imagine this is still somethin' y'want, so [you might want to update your link](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5602/community-promotion-ads-2013).